# Crop a given image using PhotoChooserTask

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone app, users can choose photos using the `PhotoChooserTask` and they're cropped to required dimensions by specifying `photoChooserTask.PixelWidth` and `photoChooserTask.PixelHeight`.

However, users can also get to my app through an image's edit button (using the `Photos_Extra_Image_Editor` extension). The problem is that those images can have arbitrary dimensions, so I'd like to use WP's built-in cropping mechanism here as well. Is it possible to configure the `PhotoChooserTask` to use one specific image and skip the choosing part? Or is there a task specifically for cropping?

Answer (score 1):

The [Nokia Imaging SDK](http://developer.nokia.com/lumia/nokia-apis/imaging) has some built in controls for photo cropping.

Here is an example using the [CropFilter](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Imaging_API_Ref/nokiagraphicsimaging-namespace/cropfilter-class.html) class:

```
async void CaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    // Create a source to read the image from PhotoResult stream
    using (var source = new StreamImageSource(e.ChosenPhoto))
    {
        // Create effect collection with the source stream
        using (var filters = new FilterEffect(source))
        {
            // Initialize the filter 
            var sampleFilter = new CropFilter(new Windows.Foundation.Rect(0, 0, 500, 500));

            // Add the filter to the FilterEffect collection
            filters.Filters = new IFilter[] { sampleFilter };

            // Create a target where the filtered image will be rendered to
            var target = new WriteableBitmap((int)ImageControl.ActualWidth, (int)ImageControl.ActualHeight);

            // Create a new renderer which outputs WriteableBitmaps
            using (var renderer = new WriteableBitmapRenderer(filters, target))
            {
                // Render the image with the filter(s)
                await renderer.RenderAsync();

                // Set the output image to Image control as a source
                ImageControl.Source = target;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. The problem is that this would need some custom mechanism to allow users to chose which part to crop and thus kill consistency with the built-in mechanism.

Comment: Understood, but unfortunately there's no built in mechanism to achieve what you want. So using Nokia Imaging, or creating your own crop tool that mimics the PhotoChooserTask crop would be your only options.